# Welche Sprache gibt man bei Übersetzung von Fremdwörtern in der Klammer an?

Tags: scientific-language

Wikipedia [schreibt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Box_(Systemtheorie)#Wortherkunft)

> Eine Black Box (engl. schwarze Kiste) ist eine...

aber ich gebe ja die deutsche Übersetzung an, sollte es also nicht

> Eine Black Box (deu. schwarze Kiste) ist eine...

sein? Welcher Logik folgt die angegebene Sprache in den Klammer?

**Gibt es feste Regeln oder ist das weitgehend Geschmackssache?**

Comment: Bitte nur eine Frage je Frage. Zum Thema Sprache: Man könnte auch _Eine Black Box (engl., schwarze Kiste) ist eine..._  (man beachte das Komma) und _Eine Black Box (deu.: schwarze Kiste) ist eine..._ (mit Doppelpunkt) verwenden.

Comment: Den Erläuterungstext in den Klammern würde ich kurz halten. Z. B. engl. für XXX oder weglassen, wenn die Sprache offensichtlich ist, aus der das Wort stammt.

Comment: Gute Frage! Eine offizielle Regel ist mir nicht bekannt. Tatsächlich scheint sich Wikipedia [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_(Michael-Jackson-Lied)) selbst zu widersprechen. Ich bevorzuge die (deut.)-Variante, weil das dem Sprachgebrauch näher kommt, man würde eher sagen: „Eine Black Box, zu gut Deutsch auch...“.

Comment: Dass die Übersetzung deutsch ist wird wohl jeder Leser verstehen. Da es hier einfachste englische Vokabeln sind ist die Übersetzung wohl meist generell überflüssig. Bei weniger bekannten Sprachen und Begriffen ist allenfalls die Herkunftssprache eine interessante Information.

Comment: "Wikipedia schreibt" ist, finde ich, schon mal eine schiefe Darstellung der Dinge. Es gibt ja keine zentralisiert arbeitende Wikipedia-Redaktion, wie es etwa mal eine Brockhaus-Redaktion gab oder eine Duden-Redaktion noch gibt. Vielmehr veröffentlichen auf der Plattform Wikipedia verschiedenste berufene und unberufende Geister ihre teils fundierten, teils weniger fundierten Auffassungen. Da trifft man auch auf viele absurde Maschen und Marotten. Dein "(engl. schwarze Kiste)" würde in einem ordentlich verlegten Buch schlichtweg so nicht vorkommen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich nehme mal ein anderes Beispiel:

> Ein Ficktelefon (deu. Mobiltelefon) ist ein ...

Weißt du jetzt, aus welcher Sprache das Wort *Ficktelefon* kommt? Das wirst du vermutlich nur wissen, wenn du mal in Schweden warst, oder Schwedisch sprichst. (Schwedisch *ficka* = deutsch *Tasche* im Sinn von *Hosentasche, Jackentasche*, aber nicht *Handtasche*)

Oder:

> Ein Pyjama (deu. Schlafanzug) ist ein ...

Auch hier erfährt man nur, was das Fremdwort auf Deutsch bedeutet, erfährt aber nicht, aus welcher Sprache das Wort stammt. Da sind diese Angaben informativer:

> Ein Ficktelefon (schwedisch für *Mobiltelefon*) ist ein ...
>   Ein Pyjama (hindi/persisch für *Schlafanzug*) ist ein ...

Comment: Schöne Antwort, aber ich hätte nicht gedacht, dass mir bei Lektüre hier in diesem Forum einmal das Wort *click bait* (deutsch gerne: Klickfang) einfallen würde.

Comment: Wäre nett wenn du noch eine Empfehlung für den konkreten Fall geben würdest. `Eine Black Box (englisch für schwarze Kiste)...`?

Comment: Diese Antwort wäre noch besser, wenn du in einem Satz die Essenz deiner Antwort schreibst. Sonst existiert die Aussage nur als platonische Idee hinter den Beispielen.